# stream partial views in Ruby on Rails 3.2+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, partial-views, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking for a railsy way to stream partial views in Rails 3.2+. Right now streaming is supported only for yielding parts in layout from template via *provide*. 
But say I have *n* posts on a blog page, each post is generated in partial in about 300ms (please don't ask why it's so long) and I want user to start reading the first post immediately as it's ready.

Is it possible in rails now? Is there a way to explicitly "flush" the generated output like in php?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your loading scheme is in your controller so I would be very curious to see that. I would personally only load ahead a few 'posts' since you want to provide an enjoyable user experience.

So I would try something like this (pseudo):

***Controller&Helper:***

```
def index
  @posts = Posts.load_active
  #other control logic
end

def self.load_active
  @posts.find(:all, :conditions => "whatevs:, :limit => your_magic_number)
end

def load_next(pointer)
     @posts.find(:all, :conditions =>  ["index > (?)", pointer], :limit => ymn)
end
```

The key to it all is the javascript that would tie it all together. I am curious about how you are handling this and hopefully you can imagine a scenario where you can actively call for an update depending on the current location of the reader.

Also to address your point about a flush equivalent. Unfortunately Rails does not support streaming regular requests. However you may want to look into something like [the Action Controler::Streaming] if you hadn't checked it out already[1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html). Since you have >3.1 you might as well utilize it.

If you have any questions hit me up and I'll do my best to assist. Sorry if my pseudo-code was too brief for the description

Comment: Thank you Dan! This approach (splitting loading of a big page into several requests to server) is of course obvious and right. But I was looking for streaming the _body_ of regular requests, as it seemed to me useless to give the functionality of `provide` method in rails without enabling page to stream its repeating contents.

Comment: aw i see what you are trying to do. Pretty much a running stream of the body that will update with the users location of viewing? I can try to whip something up for a streaming of the body

Comment: Exactly.
Well, that would be nice. Although I don't have to solve this issue anymore, other people will get the answer.